# how to format the entire excel sheet to text in C#

Tags: c#, excel

i have tried using Used `range` , but its not working....
in this code before loading the data to the `datatable`, i want to format it as text so that all the values will be loaded into the datatable, bcoz some of the values are not loading into the datatable and that particular `cells` remain `empty` though it has `value` like `020, 5EH` etc.

```
namespace Data_Consistency
{

    public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window
    {
        Excelhelper g_objExcelHelper = new Excelhelper();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void tb_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Browse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
                openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
                openFileDialog1.Title = "Browse Text Files";
                bool? l_dialogResult = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
                if (l_dialogResult.HasValue && l_dialogResult.Value)
                {
                    tb.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                    string filepath = tb.Text;
                    string file_ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filepath);
                    string l_connection = "";
                    string l_selectedSheet = cb.Text;
                    string l_inputSheetRange = tb1.Text;
                    string l_connectionString = "";
                    string l_filePath = tb.Text;
                    string l_fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(l_filePath);
                    /*  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                      string workbookPath = l_filePath;
                      Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath);
                      Worksheet xlWorksheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets[1];

                      Range cells = xlWorksheet.Cells;
                      cells["A:AZ"].NumberFormat = "@";
                      excelWorkbook.Save();*/
                    if (file_ext == ".xlsx" || file_ext == ".xls" || file_ext == ".xlsm")
                    {
                        if (file_ext == ".xls")
                            l_connection = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + l_filePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1';";
                        else
                        {


                            l_connection = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + l_filePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'";
                            l_connection = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + l_filePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;MAXSCANROWS=0'";
                        }
                        Excelhelper ex = new Excelhelper();
                        string[] sheetnames = ex.GetExcelSheetNames(l_connection);
                        foreach (string item in sheetnames)
                        {
                            if (!item.EndsWith("$'") && !item.EndsWith("$"))
                                continue;
                            string l_item = item.Substring(0, item.IndexOf("$"));
                            if (l_item.StartsWith("'"))
                            {
                                l_item = item.Substring(1, item.IndexOf("$") - 1);
                            }
                            cb.Items.Add(l_item);


                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("please select the file.");
                    }
                }
            }


            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("DialogResult Value is null", "Data Consistency Tool", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }
        }






        private void tb1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void Apply_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            string l_selectedSheet = cb.Text;
            string l_inputSheetRange = tb1.Text;
            string l_connectionString = "";
            string l_filePath = tb.Text;
            string l_fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(l_filePath);

            if (l_fileExt.CompareTo(".xls") == 0)
                l_connectionString = @"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + l_filePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HRD=NO;IMEX=0';ImportMixedTypes=Text"; 
            else
            {


                l_connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + l_filePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'";
                l_connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + l_filePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;MAXSCANROWS=0'";
            }

            g_objExcelHelper.g_objDtInput = g_objExcelHelper.GetDataTable(l_connectionString, l_selectedSheet, l_inputSheetRange, g_objExcelHelper.g_objDtInput);


        }

        private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void tb2_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void ApplyButton_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string l_selectedSheet = cb1.Text;
            string l_inputSheetRange = tb3.Text;
            string l_connectionString = "";
            string l_filePath = tb2.Text;
            string l_fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(l_filePath);
            if (l_fileExt.CompareTo(".xls") == 0)
                l_connectionString = @"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + l_filePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HRD=NO;IMEX=0';ImportMixedTypes=Text";
            else
            {


                l_connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + l_filePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'";
                l_connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + l_filePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;MAXSCANROWS=0'";
            }
            g_objExcelHelper.g_objDtInput = g_objExcelHelper.GetDataTable(l_connectionString, l_selectedSheet, l_inputSheetRange, g_objExcelHelper.g_objDtInput);
        }

        private void tb3_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Search_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
                openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
                openFileDialog1.Title = "Browse Text Files";
                bool? l_dialogResult = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
                if (l_dialogResult.HasValue && l_dialogResult.Value)
                {
                    tb2.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                    string filepath = tb2.Text;
                    string file_ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filepath);
                    string l_connection = "";
                    if (file_ext == ".xlsx" || file_ext == ".xls" || file_ext == ".xlsm")
                    {
                        if (file_ext == ".xls")
                            l_connection = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1';";
                        else
                            l_connection = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';";
                        Excelhelper ex = new Excelhelper();
                        string[] sheetnames = ex.GetExcelSheetNames1(l_connection);
                        foreach (string item in sheetnames)
                        {
                            if (!item.EndsWith("$'") && !item.EndsWith("$"))
                                continue;
                            string l_item = item.Substring(0, item.IndexOf("$"));
                            if (l_item.StartsWith("'"))
                            {
                                l_item = item.Substring(1, item.IndexOf("$") - 1);
                            }
                            cb1.Items.Add(l_item);


                        }
                    }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("please select the file.");
                }
                }
            }



            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("DialogResult Value is null", "Data Consistency Tool", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below solution worked for me..

```
string l_connectionString = "";

string l_filePath = txtComparisonFile.Text;     

string l_fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(l_filePath);

if(l_fileExt.CompareTo(".xls") == 0)

      l_connectionString = @"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + l_filePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HRD=Yes;IMEX=1';"; 

else
      l_connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + l_filePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';";
                    Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
                    excelApp.Visible = false;
                    string workbookPath = l_filePath;
                    Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath,
                            0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
                            true, false, 0, true, false, false);
                    Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;
                    string currentSheet = l_selectedSheet;
                    Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet);
                    Excel.Range excelCell = (Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range(l_comparisonSheetRange);
                    excelWorksheet.Columns.NumberFormat = "@";
                    excelWorkbook.Save();
                    excelWorkbook.Close();
                    g_objExcelHelper.g_objDtCompare = g_objExcelHelper.GetDataTable(l_connectionString, l_selectedSheet, l_comparisonSheetRange, g_objExcelHelper.g_objDtCompare);
```

Answer (score 0):

The OLEDB component guesses the column type by reading the first few rows of the excel table.
If you define the column types of the datatable you are reading into you can read the values properly.

Comment: by default it considers the first 8 rows and based on majority it decides, so if after 8 rows we have different datatype like string then also its datataype will be defined by the datatype of first 8 rows

Answer (score 0):

> AS you have mentioned you have DataTable as input, I have achieved solution for this kind of issue previously hope it helps. I made a copy of a `DataTable` which contained all source table values in string format. In below method I have handled numbers,date time,and percentage types ,you can add further data types in condition

```
  private static void CopyValues(DataTable source, ref DataTable dest)
    { 
        dest = source.Clone();
        dest.Rows.Clear();
        double roundValue;

        foreach (DataRow sourcerow in source.Rows)
        {
            //create new row in based on dest table 
            DataRow destRow = dest.NewRow();

            foreach (DataColumn colname in dest.Columns)
            {
                    if (Double.TryParse(sourcerow[colname.ColumnName].ToString(), out roundValue) && dest.Columns[colname.ColumnName].Ordinal != 0)
                    {

                        if (colname.ColumnName.Contains("%"))
                        {
                            destRow[colname.ColumnName] = string.Format(new CultreInfo("en-US"), "{0} %", roundValue);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //if the value is in double format /numerical format then we store it in format of c2 i.e. "0.00"
                            //add data to column
                            destRow[colname.ColumnName] = roundValue.ToString("c2");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (sourcerow[colname.ColumnName].GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
                    {
                        //if the data is in form of date time then convert it to d/MM/YYYY format
                        destRow[colname.ColumnName] = Convert.ToDateTime(sourcerow[colname.ColumnName]).ToString("d/MM/yyyy");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //if the data is of any other form simply add it to dest datatable
                        destRow[colname.ColumnName] = sourcerow[colname.ColumnName].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            //add row to datatable 
            dest.Rows.Add(destRow);

        }
    }
```

**FootNotes:-**

If you are using Interop to export excel note that it is very slow.Also it requires excel to be installed on the client system. You can use EPPlus dll [(example)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/export-to-excel-using-epplus1) which is faster and lightweight compared to Interop.

Answer (score 0):

**Please see the code below**

```
string finalColLetter = string.Empty;
string excelRange = string.Format("A1:{0}{1}",finalColLetter, dataTable.Rows.Count + 1);

excelSheet.Range[excelRange, Type.Missing].NumberFormatLocal = "@";
excelSheet.Range[excelRange, Type.Missing].NumberFormat = "@";
```